# How to set legend outside three-dimensional axes in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am working with a basic 3D scatterplot in matplotlib. A simple example of the code is the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

XX = np.array([[1,6,7,3,2],[8,11,7,5,12],[2,7,1,30,12],[15,3,17,2,1]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

xs = XX[indx, 0]
ys = XX[indx, 1]
zs = XX[indx, 2]


for i in range(11):
    ax.scatter3D(xs, ys, zs, c='b', marker='o', label='item'+str(i), s=100.5, alpha=1)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.title('Number of Components = 3')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=7)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Following is my output plot:

[image]

In my output plot, the legend overlaps with the label for Z-axis. I want to place the legend outside of the three dimensional axis box, **preferably to the right of the plot** (i.e. to the right of ZLabel)  **such that it doesn’t overlap with anything**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general strategy to place the legend out of the plot is shown in [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132)

Here you may want to leave some more space to the right and move the legend even further to the right

```
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.07, 0.5), fontsize=7)
```

[image]